# Run docker with dynamic parameter

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm trying to run a java application on a docker container where the jvm argument of the java program would be dynamic.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM amazonlinux
ADD http://company.com/artifactory/bins-release-local/com/marc/1.3.1/marc-1.3.1.tar.gz /root/
ADD log4j2.xml /root/
RUN tar xzf /root/marc-1.3.1.tar.gz -C /root && rm -f /root/marc-1.3.1.tar.gz
RUN yum install -y java
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "-c", "/usr/bin/java", "${JVM_ARGS}", "-jar", "/root/marc.jar"]
```

I try to run the container like so:

```
docker run --rm -it --env-file jvm_args.env -e CLIENT=google moshe/java:latest
```

And the `jvm_args.env` is:

```
JVM_ARGS=-d64
-Dicmq=${CLIENT}
-Dlog4j.configurationFile=/root/log4j2.xml
-server
```

I couldn't seem to get it to work. I need the client to be dynamic and the JVM_ARGS should contain the client.
Ideas?

Comment: So, you wanna use your JVM_ARGS environment variable inside container ?

Comment: @TruongDang correct sir.

Comment: You can mount your jvm_args.env to inside your container...

Comment: I added this: `ADD jvm_args.env /root/` and changed ENTRYPOINT to this: `ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "-c", "source", "/root/jvm_args.env", "&&", "/usr/bin/java", "${JVM_ARGS}", "-jar", "/root/marc.jar"]` and I get an error sourcing the file `/root/jvm_args.env: line 0: source: filename argument required
source: usage: source filename [arguments]`. What's the right way?

Comment: Change it to `"source /root/jvm_args.env"`.  The `-c` option take a single argument and what you need to pass is the whole command.

Comment: Have you tried with "env.list" file name and also check formatting to define multiple variables : https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#set-environment-variables--e---env---env-file